# Writing a rotational rattling animation while simultaneously tracking mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

The rattling animation I want is pretty much exactly like in this clip here (but without the little windup): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmvS4mzWUkQ

I'm going to bind function to a `click()` for my pictures, but I'm having troubles figuring out how to do the animation with JS or even pure CSS if possible (if there's a better tool for this, please let me know)...

My idea is it'd look something like:

```
function rattleHead() {
    $("#woodsprite-head").css("transform", "rotate(" + (baseAngle + 45) + "deg)");
    $("#woodsprite-head").css("transform", "rotate(" + (baseAngle - 35) + "deg)");
    $("#woodsprite-head").css("transform", "rotate(" + (baseAngle + 20) + "deg)");
    $("#woodsprite-head").css("transform", "rotate(" + (baseAngle - 5) + "deg)");
    $("#woodsprite-head").css("transform", "rotate(" + (baseAngle + 0) + "deg)");
};
```

And just for another layer of complexity, this image is currently already actively rotating to follow the mouse movement on screen (we'll call that the baseAngle from above). So, do I need to stop the tracking() function while my rattle() is executing?

Lastly, I feel the code above is just going to jump to each angle frame, rather than rotate from one angle to the next in an animated style. Is it possible to incorporate this somehow?

Comment: You are rotating by radiants (vs degress) change `rad` to `deg`

Comment: @Ahmad good catch, updated

Comment: 3.141592 rad = 180 degrees

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, CSS has built-in support for animation - it's called [transitions](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp). You just need a style such as:

```
<style>
  #woodsprite-head {
    transition: 30ms linear all;
  }
</style>
```

Of course, you can start with 300ms to make it easier to see the smooth transition, but for a rattle effect you’re going to want the transition to be fairly quick.